# Python Tuple out of range

Tags: python, tuples

i keep getting the error IndexError: tuple out of range and i was hoping you guys could help me with my program

```
MIN_ROW = 0
MAX_ROW = 3
MIN_COLUMN = 0
MAX_COLUMN = 19
```

Problem seems to persist at the line 7

```
def display(theMap):
r = 0
c = 0
print("PLAYER MAP")
for r in range (0, (MAX_ROW + 1), 1):
    for c in range (0, (MAX_COLUMN + 1), 1):
        print(theMap[r][c])   #this line
    print()
print()

def loadMap():
theMap = []
for r in range(0,(MAX_ROW+1), 1):
    theMap.append([])
    for c in range(0,(MAX_COLUMN+1), 1):
        theMap[r].append(" ")
#           0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11    12   13   14   15   16    17   18   19 
map  [0] =   "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"
map  [1] =   "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"
map  [2] =   "|r|","| |", "| |", "| |", "| |", "| |", "| |", "| |", "| |", "| |", "|" 
map  [3] =   "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"
return theMap
```

So im not sure how my tuple is out of range but hoping you guys can point out and help me out

Comment: Please post what `map` looks like before you call `display(map)`

Comment: Also, you've missed the 'n' off 'MAX_COLUMN' declaration, but you've spelt it correctly in the `range`.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget i've added my code for map as well

Comment: @JeremyN: is this python 3k?

Comment: You need to fix the indentation. Also, you shouldn't call a variable `map`, because that's a built-in function. Also, you don't need to define `r` before using it in a `for` loop, and in fact it's likely to lead to confusion (this isn't C).

Comment: @inspectorG4dget, yes, python 3

Comment: Also, `print(map[r][c])` is going to put each cell on its own line. I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: @abamert, yes it is actually, i'm trying to create each thing on it's own line. If it helps, i provided a link that shows how this board or map should look like

Comment: The link you showed doesn't have each cell on its own line; it has one line per row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing things with explicit loops often leads to problems that are hard to debug. That's why Python doesn't force you to do so, and in fact encourages you not to:

```
def display(theMap):
    print("PLAYER MAP")
    for row in theMap:
        for col in row:
            print(col)
        print()
    print()
```

This still isn't really what you want, because `print(col)` prints a newline. You don't want each cell on its own line, you want spaces between the cells, and each row on its own line. To get that, you have to `print(col, end=' ')` instead.

Or, more simply:

```
def display(theMap):
    print("PLAYER MAP")
    for row in theMap:
        print(' '.join(row))
    print()
```

Or, even more concisely—but probably not as simply:

```
def display(theMap):
    print("PLAYER MAP")
    print('\n'.join(' '.join(row) for row in theMap))
    print()
```

You can similarly improve theMap by just creating theMap in one pass, instead of creating empty rows, then replacing them. For example:

```
def loadMap():
    return [
        ("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"),
        ("-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"),
        ("|r|","| |", "| |", "| |", "| |", "| |", "| |", "| |", "| |", "| |", "|"),
        ("-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-")]
```

In general, whenever you find yourself writing `for i in range(something)` in Python, you're doing something unnecessary that you're just going to end up debugging.

Now, you could argue that this style doesn't "catch errors". But doing things with explicit loops only catches a handful of errors, and catches them in a way that's very hard to debug. if you know your preconditions, you can usually write them much more simply and clearly:

```
theMap = loadMap()
assert(all(len(row) == len(theMap[0]) for row in theMap))
```

Also, if you know what the output of a test case should be, you can write unit tests that verify the output.

Anyway, even after fixing all of this, you're still going to have some problems. For example, besides the fact that row 2 is a few columns shorter than the other rows, the individual columns in that row are 3x as big as the ones in the other rows, so it's not going to line up at all. But once you've got it running, it should be easier to debug the visual stuff.

Taking a step back, you obviously are going to be advancing the 'r' through row 2. In fact, all you probably need to represent the map is the width and the current position:

```
def display(mapWidth, playerPosition):
    print('PLAYER MAP')
    # Display the first line. This is the header, with a label for each of the
    # mapWidth columsn, with a space between each label, and an extra space at
    # the start, like ' 0 1 2 3 4'. The ' '.join(s) creates a new string by 
    # putting a space between each element of s. The '012...XYZ'[:mapWidth] 
    # just takes the first mapWidth characters of the longer string. 
    print(' ' + ' '.join('0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'[:mapWidth]))

    # Display the second line. This is just a '-' for each column, with a space
    # between each, and an extra space at the start, like ' - - - - -'. The join
    # works the same as above; the '-' * mapWidth creates a string with mapWidth
    # copies of '-'.
    print(' ' + ' '.join('-' * mapWidth))

    # Display the third line. This is the trickiest. This is cell for each column,
    # where the first playerPosition cells are '| |', the playerPositionth is 
    # '|r|', and the rest are again '| |', with no space between them. It seemed
    # simpler to treat this as a group of playerPosition+1 '|' characters with 
    # spaces between, an 'r' character, and a group of mapWidth-playerPosition
    # '|' characters with spaces between again, but there are various different 
    # ways of printing something equivalent. The only new thing here is the 
    # end='' keyword argument--without that, each print ends with a newline.
    print(' '.join('|' * (playerPosition + 1)), end='')
    print('r', end='')
    print(' '.join('|' * (mapWidth - playerPosition)))

    # Fourth line, same as the second.
    print(' ' + ' '.join('-' * mapWidth))
    print()
```

You might find this a bit simpler to read, depending on your familiarity with the `join` method, the `print` function, etc.:

```
def display(mapWidth, playerPosition):
    print('PLAYER MAP')
    print(' ' + ' '.join('0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'[:mapWidth]))
    print(' -' * mapWidth)
    print(' '.join('|' * (playerPosition + 1)) +
          'r' +
          ' '.join('|' * (mapWidth - playerPosition)))
    print(' -' * mapWidth)
    print()
```

It's worth thinking through why, e.g., `' ' + ' '.join('-' * 8)` is the same thing as `' -' * 8`.

Yet another way to do the tricky third line is:

```
   # Print mapWidth '|' characters, each followed by a ' ', except for the one
   # at the player position, which is followed by an 'r'. Then we still need one
   # more '|' at the end.
   print(''.join('|' + (' ' if i != playerPosition else 'r') 
                 for i in range(mapWidth) + '|')
```

I think this is the easiest one to explain in English, but translating it to Python requires generator expressions, and ternary if expressions, both of which you probably don't want to learn just yet—and the end result is something even an experience Python developer probably doesn't want to read.

Of course when in doubt, you can always pull things out into separate lines, or even separate functions, to make them more readable:

```
    cellsBeforePlayer = '| ' * playerPosition
    cellsWithPlayer = cellsBeforePlayer + '|r|'
    cellsToEnd = cellsWithPlayer + '| ' * (mapWidth - playerPosition)
    print(cellsToEnd)
```

At any rate, these all do the same thing:

```
>>> display(MAX_COLUMN - MIN_COLUMN + 1, 3)
PLAYER MAP
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F G H I J
 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
| | | |r| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |
 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

Unless those `MIN_COLUMN` and `MAX_COLUMN` values are part of the requirements, I'd use a single `COLUMNS=20` variable instead—again, it avoids another common off-by-one error (that `+ 1` in the function call, which is very easy to forget to include when needed, or to add incorrectly when not needed).

Or, if the map width is fixed, it's even simpler:

```
def display(playerPosition):
    print('PLAYER MAP')
    print(' ' + ' '.join('0123456789ABCDEFGHIJ'))
    print(' -' * 20)
    print(' '.join('|' * (playerPosition + 1)) +
          'r' +
          ' '.join('|' * (20 - playerPosition)))
    print(' -' * 20)
    print()
```

At any rate, the advantage of this goes beyond the simplicity in `display` and not needing `loadMap` at all—to move the player, instead of this:

```
theMap[2][playerPosition] = '| |'
playerPosition += stepsMoved
theMap[2][playerPosition] = '|r|'
display(theMap)
```

You just do this:

```
playerPosition += stepsMoved
display(playerPosition)
```

Your entire game state is reduced from a complicated list of lists to a single integer.

Comment: so you think the part above the map of my original function loadMap() is unnecessary?

Comment: @JeremyN: Yes, it's completely unnecessary. You're creating a list, appending 4 lists, then going through and filling those lists in, and then throwing them all away to replace each one with a tuple. Just create a list of the tuples in the first place.

Comment: ahhh , i see your point, yes it does seem tedious. I think the way i was thinking was cause it should be set, for i'm going to have that "r" running through the program

Comment: @JeremyN: That means changing `theMap[2][oldValue]='| |'` and `theMap[2][newValue]='|r|'`. But since both versions define `theMap[2]` the exact same way, there's no difference between the two. Python doesn't remember that you originally defined it as a list of spaces and then threw that list away and replaced it with a tuple of different strings, all it knows is that it's currently a tuple of different strings.

Comment: @JeremyN: Also, you won't be able to change `theMap[2][oldValue]` either in your version or in my modified version, because each row is a `tuple` rather than a `list`. Replace the parentheses with square brackets if you need to fix that. But really, I don't think you want this structure at all—see my last edit.

Comment: ahh , see what you've done. How does the display(mapWidth, playerPosition) work?

Comment: I've updated the first version with lots of comments that hopefully explain things. (The reason I thought displaying the `| |` and `|r|` cells would be less simple than just displaying the borders was that if you think about it, each cell shares a character with the next cell, which makes things complicated.)

Comment: as beautiful as this is, it says that this line (print(' '.join('|' * (playerPosition + 1)), end='') has a syntax error? Is it due to the double parentheses after playerPosition?

Comment: You've got an extra `(` before the `print`. Is that there in your code? Also, if you just define `playerPosition=20` then copy and paste that line into an interpreter, does it work? If not, it should show you were the error is with a `^` pointer. Meanwhile, I just assumed you were using Python 3, because you wrote `print` with parentheses, but… are you using Python 2? Because, if so, the `end='') will raise a `SyntaxError` (at the `=`).

Answer (score 1):

`map[2]` seems to be formatted differently to the other rows. This means it doesn't have 20 elements to iterate over. That would cause the error you are seeing.

Also, `map()` is a builtin function, so you might want to choose a different name to avoid confusion.

In this case, you should avoid iterating over the map using indices, and just iterate over the tuples anyway

```
def display(the_map):
    print("PLAYER MAP")
    for row in the_map:
        for cell in row:
            print(cell)
        print()
    print()
```

Or perhaps

```
def display(the_map):
    print("PLAYER MAP")
    for row in the_map:
        print(''.join(row))
    print()
```

Edit: now there is more information, here is a simpler very explicit way to implement your map

```
def display(the_map):
    print(the_map[0].replace("", " "))
    print(the_map[1].replace("", " "))
    print(the_map[2].replace("", "|"))
    print(the_map[3].replace("", " "))

the_map = ["0123456789ABCDEFGHIJ",
           "--------------------",
           "r                   ",
           "--------------------"]
display(the_map)
```

Comment: Not sure, but my TA told us to put us there. I though we could just define the actual amount of MAX_ROW and MAX_COLUMN and could be done with it

Comment: But `map[3]` actually exists. Looks like `MAX_*` refer to the max legal indices

Comment: thanks for the useful hint, it might look a little confusing because this is a map or board-like game we are supposed to create

Comment: @inspectorG4dget, ah now it is added to the question. looks like `map[2]` is a bit short though

Comment: You're absolutely right! That short `map[2]` is what's causing the error

Comment: @JeremyN, check the formatting of map[2]. All the other rows are tuples of single chars.

Comment: @JeremyN, yes. you are trying to access items past the end of `map[2]`

Comment: @gnibbler, looking at the link i provided, i have to add the correct amount of items for this to work?

Comment: @gnibbler, no it's not provided that access the items at the end of map[2] but it's just that i'm having trouble drawing this board out unforutnately

Comment: @JeremyN, you can try that, you seem to be doubling up the `"|"` though

Comment: i did double it up, but i guess it's better not to double it up because then it confuses and says index would be out of range